# Try to download file from server

Tags: library, download

I'm trying to download a file from my local computer, which is in a library sharepoint. I'm using this function :

```
        try
        {
                siteURL += "?NoRedirect=true";
                System.Net.WebClient _WebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
                _WebClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                // Downloads the resource with the specified URI to a local file.
                _WebClient.DownloadFile(siteURL, saveName);
        }
        catch (Exception _Exception)
        {
            // Error
            //MessageBox.Show("Error In Downloading");
        }
```

and where saveName is equal to : 
    string pathToDesktop = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%USERPROFILE%") + @"\Desktop" + "\Export-" + filenamexls;

The thing is that i want to download the file on my computer and not on the server. But I don't know how to do this.

Can someone help me on this one ?

Comment: Are you trying to push **from server** a file **to client computer** ?

Comment: Where is the code you're writing running?

Comment: Does SiteURL point to a specific file or the site itself?  Are you getting an error - if so, what?

Comment: @SteveB Yes that's exactly what i want to do. My code is running on the server

Comment: SiteURL is pointing to a specific site, and i'm not getting any error, the only problem is that the file is downloaded into the desktop's server and not the one of my computer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint

Comment: I've found the solution : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't **push** the file to the client from the server. The server side has **no knowledge** of the client side. You have to write a client application, that will **pull** the file.

First, you'll have to know the url of the file.

Then, a simple

```
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
wc.DownloadFile(targetFile, @"c:\temp\myfile.txt");
```

would do the job (assuming windows authentication and access to the file granted).

Answer (score 3):

If your client code is running on server which means that request is being sent from server and your file will eventually downloaded on server. I would recommend you to write a code which runs on your computer and download the file from Server. You can Lists.asmx or OOTB Web Service to download the file from the Server.